# How do I execute my PHP script by calling it on another PHP script?

Tags: php, smarty

I want to execute a php script in background by calling it in another file.

For e.g. : 
you have two files file1.php & file2.php.
Begin execution of file2.php in file1.php

Note : without using include statement in file1.php

Comment: If you dont like "include" use "require" :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use this PHP function http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php
But what you want it very wierd wishes :)

Comment: I have tried by using exec() but it doesn't work.

exec('http://www.xyz.com/file2.php');

Comment: This weird wish is because just want to extend current working of application & don't want to disturb it's working functionality.

Answer (score 0):

for background usage in php :

1. ajax call from client ( server tell client to ajax )
2. gearman
3. curl to yourself without waiting for a response.

if you usage a particular framework , let us know so we can tell you how to do it.

i recommend for start , try using the curl method.

Answer (score 0):

Please use ajax on page load of file1.php

Comment: I want to do it in background & I don't need output of file2.php

Answer (score 0):

If both of your files are in same folder then in file1

```
    exec('php file2.php');
```

or provide appropriate file path for file2.